# Why does my externally hosted React component break when loaded through NPM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I've written a nicely self contained component, it works as expected inside the initial project I built it for.

I'd like to eventually release the library as a NPM module, so I thought I'd start by loading the library from another repo via NPM.

In my new project I've defined the path to the library's repo in my `package.json` and it's being pulled down by NPM fine, Webpack is successfully compiling it into my bundle, but when I run the code in the browser I get:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a
ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component
that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have
multiple copies of React loaded (details:
https://reactjs.org/warnings/refs-must-have-owner.html).
```

The project has React in it's dependencies, the library I'm pulling in imports has React as a devDependency in it's own package.json.

I've read around the problem and the problem seems to stem from either 2 copies of React, I've rm -rf'ed my node_modules dir cleared my cache and reinstalled everything. Or that you can't add a ref attribute outside a render function, which I'm not doing.

Comment: Yes, you likely have two copies of React. You have to add React  as `peerDependency` to the component you want to reuse, it should install its own version of React.

Comment: `peerDependecy` rather than `devDependency`?

Comment: Could also be devDependency, but peerDependency will make npm complain if the main project does not install React. I guess it could even be in both.

Comment: Thanks for the help Felix, as you can see I've solved this problem by defining some externals in the webpack config of the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my libraries Webpack config file I defined two externals like this

```
externals: {
  'react': {
    'commonjs': 'react',
    'commonjs2': 'react',
    'amd': 'react',
    // React dep should be available as window.React, not window.react
    'root': 'React'
  },
  'react-dom': {
    'commonjs': 'react-dom',
    'commonjs2': 'react-dom',
    'amd': 'react-dom',
    'root': 'ReactDOM'
  }
},
```

This solved the problem, React and ReactDOM don't get compiled into my bundle but can be referenced in the library, so when it's used in the project it can pick up the project's copy of React/ReactDOM.